# Neuronal coordinates of C.elegans

Tags: neuroscience, neuroanatomy

Is there a list of neural coordinates for *C.elegans*? I need it to build a 3D model.

**Update:**
What is available at the moment is:

- full connectome for example, at [openconnectome](http://openconnectomeproject.org);
- neuron description with images of relative position at [wormatlas](http://wormatlas.org/);
- 2d position data at [dynamic-connectome](http://www.dynamic-connectome.org/?page_id=25).

**Update 2:**

I've created very simple 3d model that consists of three layers (left, right and center) based on neuron labels. This shouldn't be considered as a real biological, but better than nothing. Code and data is on [github](https://github.com/bbrh/celegans_neuron_spatial_coordinates).

[image: celegans neurons in 3d]

**Clarification:**

The question is still there, I've provided very basic model and everyone are welcome to use it. But it still would be interesting to get experimental results. I'll keep the question open in case someone could share the data.

Comment: Any research done already? Please share or the question may be closed as 'homework' (I removed the "lazy" part in your post, but that is exactly trhe reason why this question may be put on hold :-)

Comment: nice piece of work!

Comment: Now that you have done some analysis yourself, can you clarify your exact question. You seem to have answered it yourself; if not then add some details.

Comment: I've revoked the -1 after these edits.

Answer (score 2):

The Worm Atlas you cited is *NOT* just a "model." The neuronal cell coordinates were determined from an actual 3-D reconstruction of a worm based on serial thin section electron micrographs.  The serial sections were manually digitized to permit annotation and analysis using computer graphics. The annotation (over a period of years) established the synaptic connectivity, published by John White et al. in 1986 in the Proceedings of the Royal Society of London.